# How To Correct UTF-8 Characters Stored As ASCII

Tags: python, utf-8

I have some old data that is stored in ASCII format. Clearly there is UTF-8 data that was not properly converted to ASCII before being written. For example, `José` will appear in the file as `JosÃ©`. I can easily fix this with a Java snippet code below:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = c_TOBETRANSLATED.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String s2 = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF-8");
```

But I need to do this Python with the rest of my code.  I'm only just starting in Python and my internet searches and trial and error is not helping me find a Python solution to do the same thing.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: That's not ASCII.

Comment: To my horror, I've discovered this can be intentional; a sort of Base256 with byte values converted to ISO 8859-1 characters so a byte sequence can be stored in a string datatype.

Comment: Your problem description sounds like you are using Latin-1 to view an UTF-8 file. What are the actual bytes in the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, you can do the following using the [bytes function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes):

```
test = "JosÃ©"
fixed = bytes(test, 'iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
# fixed will now contain the string José
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `"JosÃ©"` "in the file" the data was read/displayed incorrectly by the file viewer.  That *is* UTF-8 but decoded with the wrong encoding.  Example:

```
import locale

# Correctly written
with open('file.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('José')

# The default encoding for open()
print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))

# Incorrectly opened
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    # What I think you are requesting as a fix.
    # Re-encode with the incorrect encoding, then decode correctly.
    print(data.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))

# Correctly opened
with open('file.txt',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
cp1252
JosÃ©
José
José
```